# Почему окно закрывается при клике по любому месту но не закрывается на кнопку?

Tags: javascript

Кода много, поэтому не знаю, что скинуть (постарался выбрать все, что относится к проблеме). Проблема в том, что есть несколько поп апов. Все работают нормально, кроме одного (imagePopup). Открывается хорошо, но с закрытием проблемы. Закрывается при клике в любой части экрана, но на кнопку закрытия реагировать не хочет.

```js
const togglePopup = (popup) => {
  popup.classList.toggle('popup_active');
}
   
// здесь вероятное начало проблемы(но это не точно)
imagePopup.addEventListener('click', function() {
  togglePopup(imagePopup);
});

imagePopupCloseButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  togglePopup(imagePopup);
});

const showCard = (e) => {
  togglePopup(imagePopup);
  imagePopup.querySelector('.popup-image__image').src = e.target.src;
  imagePopup.querySelector('.popup-image__text').textContent = e.target.nextElementSibling.querySelector('.element-grid__text').textContent;
  imagePopupCloseButton.addEventListener('click', togglePopup);
}

// конец


addPopupCloseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  togglePopup(addPopup);
})
addForm.addEventListener('submit', addSubmitHandler);

editForm.addEventListener('submit', editSubmitHandler);

addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  togglePopup(addPopup);
});

editPopupCloseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  togglePopup(editPopup);
});
```

```html
<section class="popup-image popup " aria-label="попап">
  <div class="popup-image__container">
    <div class="popup-image__picture">
      <img alt="" class="popup-image__image" src="#">
      <div class="popup-image__text"></div>
    </div>

    <button class="popup-image__close-button" type="button"></button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю проблема в том что при клике на .popup-image__close-button, так же происходит и событие клика на .popup-image, который выполняет те же самые действия. То есть сначала происходит закрытие попапа, а потом сразу его открытие. Это называется всплытие события. Что бы этого избежать достаточно в событии клика на .popup-image__close-button указать e.stopPropagation();(только не забудьте передать "e" в качестве аргумента функции). Это остановит всплытие. Вот так:

```
imagePopupCloseButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  togglePopup(imagePopup);
});
```

Comment: К сожалению не заработало,никак не отреагировало

Comment: Событие в функцию точно передали?

Comment: Вы перепутали куда добавить e.stopPropagation(); Я же написал что в событие клика на imagePopupCloseButton, а Вы его добавили в imagePopup. Я поменял, теперь работает

Comment: да , точно на крестик закрывает теперь. Но закрывает и при клике на фото так же а мне так не нужно. Как это пофиксить ?

Comment: У вас клик на .imagePopup вызывает ровно такое же действие как и клик на .imagePopupCloseButton. Уберите событие на .imagePopup и все. 61я строчка на codepen

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало.И если не сложно можете сказать в чем проблема? 
 почему над фотографиями появляются белые рамки ?если в  классе .popup-image__container убрать max-width то рамки идут на весь экран

Comment: Вы о рамках по бокам фотографии? Если да, то у вас задан display:flex, это блочный тип и по умолчанию он стремится занять всю ширину экрана, у Вас ширина ограничена в 550px, поэтому он их и занимает, а фотография подстраивается под размеры окна и под свои размеры, поэтому и получается что видно нижний блок. Как вариант можете поменять display:flex на display:inline-flex

Comment: Благодарю еще раз